# StartsWith with any string from list to SQL request with LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I can get objects from EF with request like this:

```
apples = apples.Where(a => a.Sort.Name.StartsWith("Gold"))
```

but i wonder is it possible to user list of strings instead of one string?
I already tried do it this way:

```
List<string> list = {...}

apples = apples.Where(a => list.Any(x => a.Sort.Name.StartsWith(x)))
```

but it give me strange error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')
> at System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpression1.GetArgument(Int32 index)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionVisitors.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitLikeAnyAll(SubQueryExpression expression)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionVisitors.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionVisitors.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionVisitors.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionVisitors.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
> at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel) at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateAsyncQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileAsyncQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
> at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 118 at {my project}

Comment: What do you mean with a.Sort? Are you sorting a single apple?

Comment: Sort is an object,there is a table with all sorts, so every apple has a sort and every sort has a name. I just need to select only apples from database which sort names startswith any string from list

Comment: You need to specify which LINQ to EF you are using: EF 6.x, EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not able to get the same error as you (got just failed translation one, so it would be great if you could add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), for me  worked using `EF.Functions.ILike` (with latest npgsql package):

```
List<string> list = new() {"a%", "b%"};
var result = ctx.Apples
    .Where(c => list.Any(xx => EF.Functions.ILike(c.Sort.Name, xx)))
    .ToList();
```

As far as I can see support for using `StartsWith` with local collection is not implemented at the moment (based on [this PR](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/430) and [this comment](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/422#issuecomment-452178966)), only `EF.Functions.Like` and `EF.Functions.ILike`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) then you can create extension methods to build expression from local collections:

```
// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s))
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnyIs<T, TSearch>(this IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var s in searchTerms)
        pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

    return pred;
}

// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) =>
    dbq.AsExpandable().Where(searchTerms.AnyIs(testFne));
```

Then you can use them with your query:

```
List<string> list = {...}

apples = apples.WhereAny(list, (a,s) => a.Sort.Name.StartsWith(s));
```

Of course, you can also create your own mini-LINQKit to accomplish the same task (though it isn't quite that mini).